# A submanifold of the space positive definite matrices

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra, matrices, it.information-theory

Consider the space of $n \times n$ positive definite symmetric matrices and let $\Sigma$ be one such matrix. We make this space into a Riemannian manifold $M$ by means of the metric $$ds^2=tr(\Sigma^{-1}d\Sigma\Sigma^{-1}d\Sigma)$$
Now fix a $p<n$ and consider the collection $\Phi_p$ of all positive definite symmetric matrices which can be written
$$B^TB+D$$
for some $B$ and $D$ where $B$ is $p \times n$ and $D$ is a diagonal positive definite matrix. Here $B$ and $D$ are allowed to vary but $p$ must stay fixed. Is $\Phi_p$ an embedded submanifold of $M$ and if so how can I put the induced metric on it?

Comment: Why is the metric a metric?

Comment: In fact, if $X_1 = X_2 = I,$ the distance is not zero, which is a little sad.

Comment: This is the Fisher information matrix on the mean zero Gaussians. This metric was also investigated by Siegel in the context of symplectic geometry. A derivation of the metric can be found here http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10851-010-0255-x

Comment: But I repeat, it is NOT a metric, at least not the way you define it.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm using bad notation. Here is how Bhatia defines this metric in his book on positive definite matrices. I hope this clears things up.

Comment: So, by "realize as a Riemannian submanifold", what exactly do you mean? Do you mean "is it a smooth submanifold?" Perhaps you should give more background, otherwise the question is a little strange.

Comment: So you are asking whether the set of "diagonal posdef plus low rank semidefinite" matrices forms a manifold? It is not clear if $D$ is the one being kept fixed or $B$ is kept fixed, or neither. This question needs some more work to make it more precise.

Comment: I've restated the problem. $B$ and $D$ can vary but $p$ must be fixed. So yes, is the set of diagonal posdef plus low rank semidefinite matrices and embedded sub manifold of the set of posdef matrices.

Comment: So the first thing to test is: say $P$, $Q$ come from this diag+low-rank set. Now, is the geometric mean of $P$ and $Q$ also in this set? If not, then this won't be a submanifold (in the sense that you are searching for)...

Comment: and it seems not so clear, if this is possible. Try experimenting with the $p=1$ case....

Comment: @Suvrit why is your question equivalent to the OP's?

Comment: @Igor: I was thinking that on the psd manifold that the OP's mentioned, the geodesics have a closed form formula involving matrix geometric means----I'm just trying to construct geodesics of the same type for the restricted set of matrices the OP has. But I had no more time to think whether this will go through...

Comment: @Suvrit I understand. I don't think he expects this to be a _geodesic_ submanifold, just smooth...

Comment: @Igor: Ah ok, then I misunderstood the question!!

Comment: Smooth would be good, geodesic better. My current suspicion is that it's not even smooth.

Comment: It's not a smooth submanifold in general.  Just look at the case $(n,p)=(3,1)$, where $\Phi_1$ contains an open set, but is not open:  For $a\in\Phi_1$, you have to have $S := a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}\ge0$.  If $S>0$, then you only need that $a_{ij}^2a_{kk} > S$ for all $(i,j,k)$ a permutation of $(1,2,3)$ in order for $a$ to lie in $\Phi_1$.  Thus, $\Phi_1$ contains an open set.  However, $\Phi_1$ clearly doesn't contain a neighborhood of the identity matrix (which does lie in $\Phi$), since $S$ is not positive at the identity, so it's not an open set.

Comment: @RobertBryant a very nice answer, er, I mean, _comment_...

Comment: @IgorRivin:  Thanks.  Actually, I think that, properly worded, there is a somewhat interesting question here. The OP really should be asking about the structure of this subvariety of 'low-rank' perturbations of a flat submanifold (i.e., the diagonal matrices) of the space of quadratic forms.  It's a natural subvariety of this symmetric space, and it's conceivable that knowing something about this space has applications in information geometry.

Comment: Knowing something about this space will have direct applications to information geometry. My background is in statistics and matrix analysis so I can't word my question very well int he context of geometry. Statistically $B^TB+D$ is used to represent a factor model where the factors are normally distributed. If we can understand the geometry of factor models, we may be able to develop algorithms to fit them that work better then the typical EM approach.

Comment: Maybe you could borrow some ideas from this paper: http://web.math.princeton.edu/~bartv/matrix_completion.html

Comment: @Suvrit Thanks, I'l take a look. My ultimate goal was to inherit the metric to the "sub manifold" so that I could compute a gradient. I would then use this gradient to develop a minimization algorithm. Do you think it might be worth my time to learn a little algebraic geometry. Perhaps there are some structures on varieties I could use to accomplish my goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Riemannian metric on the full space of all positive definite matrices turns up in the paper (and others)

- [Olga Gil-Medrano, Peter W. Michor: The Riemannian manifold of all Riemannian metrics. Quarterly J. Math. Oxford (2) 42 (1991), 183--202](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/rie-met.pdf)

There are explicit formulas for geodesics and for curvature. There is only one incomplete geodesic, but the space if far from being geodesically convex.